# How to add css and js files on custom html helper ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a custom select2 using ASP.NET MVC html helpers. I'm trying to replicate what I've done on Yii 1.x(PHP). I want to create a custom helper with select2 configurations are being added when doing the strongly typed helper.

Eg.

```
@Html.Select2For(m => m.Provinces)
```

What I want is when the above code is being called. A reference to select2.js and select2.css are also being added. At the same time the js setup for the select2 are also added on the page. Any idea?

Comment: Do not even consider doing this - not only are inline scripts poor practice, you can have multiple copies of the same scripts and style sheets.

Comment: i see, but on what you have said, laravel, cake php and yii are framework that uses bad practice code?

Comment: I don't know cake php and yii :)

Comment: Thats how they do it, I have read an answer to a stack's questions saying that telerik also do the same approach but I'm not sure how they coded it. I don't have budget to buy a subscription.

Comment: Telerik do not do that - in order to use the controls, you need to include their scripts (in the main view or layout)

Comment: I see thanks, I will do the standard way then.